# Error establishing a database connection when running phpunit

Tags: wp-cli

I'm following https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/plugin-unit-tests/ to run unit tests for plugins.

I create a new plugin.

```
$ wp scaffold plugin hello-plugin-1
Success: Created plugin files.
Success: Created test files.
```

Run `install-wp-tests.sh`.

```
$ cd wp-content/plugins/hello-plugin-1
$ ./bin/install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test_1 root root localhost latest
+ install_wp
+ '[' -d /var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress/ ']'
+ return
+ install_test_suite
++ uname -s
+ [[ Darwin == \D\a\r\w\i\n ]]
+ local ioption=-i.bak
+ '[' '!' -d /var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib ']'
+ '[' '!' -f wp-tests-config.php ']'
+ download https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/tags/5.4/wp-tests-config-sample.php /var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
++ which curl
+ '[' /usr/bin/curl ']'
+ curl -s https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/tags/5.4/wp-tests-config-sample.php
++ echo /var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress/
++ sed 's:/\+$::'
+ WP_CORE_DIR=/var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress/
+ sed -i.bak 's:dirname( __FILE__ ) . '\''/src/'\'':'\''/var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress//'\'':' /var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
+ sed -i.bak s/youremptytestdbnamehere/wordpress_test_1/ /var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
+ sed -i.bak s/yourusernamehere/root/ /var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
+ sed -i.bak s/yourpasswordhere/root/ /var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
+ sed -i.bak 's|localhost|localhost|' /var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
+ install_db
+ '[' false = true ']'
+ PARTS=(${DB_HOST//\:/ })
+ local PARTS
+ local DB_HOSTNAME=localhost
+ local DB_SOCK_OR_PORT=
+ local EXTRA=
+ '[' -z localhost ']'
++ echo
++ grep -e '^[0-9]\{1,\}$'
+ '[' ']'
+ '[' -z ']'
+ '[' -z localhost ']'
+ EXTRA=' --host=localhost --protocol=tcp'
+ mysqladmin create wordpress_test_1 --user=root --password=root --host=localhost --protocol=tcp
mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

Run `phpunit` and got this DB connection error.

```
$ phpunit
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /private/var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1626
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /private/var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/install.php:0
PHP   2. require_once() /private/var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/install.php:29
PHP   3. require_wp_db() /private/var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress/wp-settings.php:126
PHP   4. wpdb->__construct() /private/var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress/wp-includes/load.php:426
PHP   5. wpdb->db_connect() /private/var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:631
PHP   6. mysqli_real_connect() /private/var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1626

wp_die called
Message : <p><code>No such file or directory</code></p>
<h1>Error establishing a database connection</h1>
<p>This either means that the username and password information in your <code>wp-config.php</code> file is incorrect or we can&#8217;t contact the database server at <code>localhost</code>. This could mean your host&#8217;s database server is down.</p>
<ul>
<li>Are you sure you have the correct username and password?</li>
<li>Are you sure you have typed the correct hostname?</li>
<li>Are you sure the database server is running?</li>
</ul>
<p>If you&#8217;re unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/forums/">WordPress Support Forums</a>.</p>

Title :
```

Do we need to set up the DB in `wp-config.php` in `/var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress` before I run phpunit? I tried it and it did not work. Any idea what went wrong?

I'm running `WP-CLI 2.4.0` and `PHPUnit 7.5.9`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in `/var/folders/qd/y3hp2mb90gx36d5swtxcndhh0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  To get this working on my localhost which is MacOS running MAMP Pro, I had change my database host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in two places...

1. My wp-config.php file

   - I did this after I got this same error when I ran `install-wp-tests.sh`
2. In the `install-wp-tests.sh` command

   - This solved the error that I got that you mentioned after running `phpunit`
   - Ex: `./bin/install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test_1 root root 127.0.0.1 latest`